# mapstruct - Propagate parent field value to collection of nested objects

Tags: java, mapstruct

Is it possible to propagate value form a parent object to collection of nested objects? For example

***Source DTO classes***

```
class CarDTO {
  private String name;
  private long userId;
  private Set<WheelDto> wheels; 
};

class WheelDto {
  private String name;
}
```

***Target entity classes***

```
class Car {
  private String name;
  private long userId;
  private Set<Wheel> wheels; 
};

class Wheel {
  private String name;
  private long lastUserId;
}
```

As you could see I do not have lastUserId on WheelDto, hence I would like to map userId from CarDto to lastUserId on WheelDto on each object in a wheels collection
I tried

```
@Mapping(target = "wheels.lastUserId", source = "userId")
```

but no luck

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to pass a property. However, you could solve this via `@AfterMapping` and / or `@Context`.

#### Update Wheel after Car mapping

This would though mean that you would need to iterate twice over the `Wheel`. It can look like

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

    Car map(CarDto carDto);

    @AfterMapping
    default void afterCarMapping(@MappingTarget Car car, CarDto carDto) {
        car.getWheels().forEach(wheel -> wheel.setLastUserId(carDto.getUserId()));
    }
}
```

#### Pass @Context while mapping wheel to have state during the mapping

If you want to iterate only once through the `Wheel` then you can pass a `@Context` object that would get the userId from the `CarDto` before mapping the car and then set it on the `Wheel` in an after mapping. This mapper can look like:

```
@Mapper
public interface CarMapper {

    Car map(CarDto carDto, @Context CarContext context);

    Wheel map(WheelDto wheelDto, @Context CarContext context);

}

public class CarContext {

    private String lastUserId;

    @BeforeMapping
    public void beforeCarMapping(CarDto carDto) {
        this.lastUserId = carDto.getUserId();
    }

    @AfterMapping
    public void afterWheelMapping(@MappingTarget Wheel wheel) {
        wheel.setLastUserId(lastUserId);
    }

}
```

The `CarContext` would be passed to the wheel mapping method.

Comment: I used second approach. Good solution, works for me.

Comment: @Filip Can you add an example of calling resulting mappers in "@Context" variant from mapper's client code? If I understand correctly, it would be something like `map(carDto, new CarContext())`, right? So you must always create a dummy context object explicitly from **client code**?

Comment: And what if `CarMapper` will be used in another mapper using `@Mapper(uses = CarMapper.class)`? How that another mapper will call `Car map(CarDto carDto, @Context CarContext context);`? Where it will get the `CarContext` object? Or do I need to add this parameter in all other mappers, which will implicitly use `CarMapper`?

Comment: I tried to use @AfterMapping like yesterday but I did something wrong, based on your example it started working. Thanks!